# PySide6 Code without errors but not working

Tags: python, qgraphicsview, pyside6, qgraphicsitem

I'm creating an engineering-oriented desktop application, i want to create an interface where it is possible to drag piping items, as well as other accessories (later), and thus set up a pneumatic network.

To do this, I'm using PySide6 and PyCharm. Apparently the IDE did not point out any errors, the code runs normally without pointing out errors either, however, nothing opens on the screen and the following message Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) appears.

Furthermore, something like a message is appearing on line 12 and 16 in PyCharm itself, which I don't know if it is related to this problem and which is also bothering me because I don't know what it is.

```
Overrides method in QGraphicsRectItem -> def paint(self, painter: QPainter, option, widget=None):

Overrides method in QGraphicsItem -> def itemChange(self, change, value):
```

**Below is the entire code:**

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsRectItem, QApplication
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter

class PipeItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, scene_width, scene_height):
        super(PipeItem, self).__init__(-50, -2.5, 100, 5)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.scene_width = scene_width
        self.scene_height = scene_height

    def paint(self, painter: QPainter, option, widget=None):
        super().paint(painter, option, widget)
        painter.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange or change == QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionHasChanged:
            new_pos = value.toPointF()
            new_pos.setX(max(new_pos.x(), -self.scene_width/2))
            new_pos.setX(min(new_pos.x(), self.scene_width/2))
            new_pos.setY(max(new_pos.y(), -self.scene_height/2))
            new_pos.setY(min(new_pos.y(), self.scene_height/2))
            return new_pos

        return super(PipeItem, self).itemChange(change, value)

# Configuração da cena e da visualização
scene_width, scene_height = 800, 600
scene = QGraphicsScene(-scene_width/2, -scene_height/2, scene_width, scene_height)
view = QGraphicsView(scene)

# Criar item de tubulação e adicionar à cena
pipe_item = PipeItem(scene_width, scene_height)
scene.addItem(pipe_item)

# Exibir a visualização
view.show()

# Executar o aplicativo
app = QApplication([])
app.exec_()
```

I really tried to look for the reason for the error, and I couldn't find it. I would appreciate it if someone is willing to help me find a solution to this, and explain to me what the problem is, so I can avoid it in the future.

Comment: move app = QApplication([]) before scene = QGraphicsScene(-scene_width/2, -scene_height/2, scene_width, scene_height)

Comment: For future reference, don't rely only on your IDE: always test your programs also in a terminal or prompt, *even if they work*. If you did it, you'd have seen a clear "QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget" message, which is a clear hint about what to do.

Comment: Also, for future reference, remove all code comments that are not in English language, as they are impossible to understand to most of the readers, and, as such, annoying as distracting.

Comment: Ok thanks guys, I feel like an idi** now, I thought it was going to be a headache but it was just a line of code. And sorry for the comments.

Comment: @GabrielZ The "messages" you see in PyCharm are simple "hints" that tell you what you're doing there: as the messages say, you are *overriding* those functions (aka, "altering" their default behavior). If you don't know what "overriding" means, I strongly suggest you to do some *serious* research on the term, as it's a fundamental aspect of OOP; then always remember that searching and studying the documentation is a **mandatory** part of programming, including checking the documentation of your IDE.